# Looking for manwha/webcomic where the blond female lead died and wakes up in the past

Tags: story-identification, manga

She was horribly abused by the royal family, especially the prince(?). She ends up loosing her eye/face scared and the only person nice to her is an outcast royal/duke. He might have been an illegitimate heir.

She ends up dying. She then wakes up in the past with all of her memories of the future intact. She decided she is not going to die and to use her knowledge to survive and I think help the kingdom. She ends up teaming up with the outcast and I think they marry?

One scene involves a bidding war with other royal ladies over a worthless piece of land and she ends up winning it even though she was stabbed. The land needed up having a tomb that had a spirit that gave them a lot of info to take down the corrupt leaders.

Comment: Do you remember if, when dying, she performed some kind of magic ritual?